# Could Amy and Rory come back by saying that they wanted to be buried in that graveyard?

Tags: doctor-who

Yes, I know that if they where to paradox it one more time, New York, and Earth would be destroyed. But, if Amy, and Rory where to put in their will that they wanted to be buried there, there would be no paradox. Couldn't they then leave the hotel?

Comment: What makes you think they were trapped in the hotel? That's not mentioned anywhere as far as I remember.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Yes, it's pretty clear that Rory and Amy weren't trapped in the Winter Quay hotel http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Quay It was destroyed when Rory caused the paradox by jumping

Answer (score 4):

Amy and Rory are not trapped in the Winter Quay. As a result of their actions in the episode, the Winter Quay never existed and is at the heart of a paradox. They're stuck in the past and incapable of seeing the Doctor again, but they are not confined to a single hotel.

They're going to *have* to be buried in that graveyard, because it's their future and they've seen it, so it must come to pass. So presumably, yes, they will arrange to be buried there, but not for any reason other than the fact that they've seen their future and have to keep it consistent in order to avoid creating another paradox.

Comment: No, it's just part of their future, that they have seen (or rather will see?) some gravestones with their names on. It doesn't mean they're buried there.

Comment: Actually, all that we saw was that two gravestones with their names and so on need to be placed in that graveyard; we have no idea whether their bodies are under there.

Comment: And even if they were in fact buried at the graveyard, it was not stated that that was a fixed point in time. They could have changed their future by insisting on a different place to be buried. They could not, however, escape from the thirties, as they didn't have a time machine.

Comment: It was stated that it was a fixed point in time. The Doctor told Amy, "once you've seen you future, it's fixed." He told her "you are creating fixed time." And with him being a Time Lord, he would be able to sense that.

Comment: Although, yes, they don't *have* to arrange to be buried there. I expect that the Pond's are savvy enough to know that they should, but even if they don't, causality will ensure that they end up there because they have to in order to end up stuck in the past anyway, because seeing their gravestone is what leads to them being sent back.